# How to print double without trailing zeros and without scientific format

Tags: c++, c++11

As far as I can gather the output format can either be in fixed, scientific or default mode.

I don't want scientific mode, so that is out.

When using fixed mode (`std::fixed`) `std::cout.precision(15)` will leave trailing zeros.

When using default mode (`std::defaultfloat`) `std::cout.precision(15)` doesn't affect anything - e.g. after 6 decimal places it still switches to scientific format.

Basically, I would like

```
std::cout << 0.1 << std::endl;
std::cout << 0.0000001 << std::endl;
```

to print

```
0.1
0.0000001
```

Comment: What does it currently print?

Comment: Depends. As given, it prints 0.1 and 1e-07. With std::fixed, it prints 0.1000000 and 0.0000001.

Comment: @Cookie You may also be interested in my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25403713/set-precision-and-clip-trailing-zeros-but-never-print-exponent