# Printf of a value converted with atof

Tags: c, floating-point, printf, atof, strtod

I'm trying to build a project for my SAM3S microcontroller. I am using the atof function to convert a string of characters passed to the micro through UART into a float, but when i want to see the result of the conversion (through printf) the value printed is only "f".

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


    int main(){ 
       char str[7];
       float number;
            //receives the string of characters through UART and saves it in str
       number=atof(str);
       printf("received: %s converted in: %lf",str,number);
    }
```

And the result of the operation is: "received 10.000 converted in: f". I also tried with `strtod(str,NULL);`
and hopelessly with even sscanf, but the value remains the same. Each calculus made with 'number'keeps returning 'f' when printed.
 I think the error is in the conversion. Do you have suggestions?
Thank you

Comment: Does your microcontroller's `printf` support floating point? It's often excluded.

Comment: @JohnH: In `printf()`, both `%lf` and `%f` take a double as an argument. If you pass a `float` to a varargs function (like printf), it will be promoted to a `double`.

Comment: try to build a simple program like `float number=atof("10.000");` and read the memory in debugger directly.

Comment: How is the string `str` insured to be `null-terminated`. Is the terminator sent through the UART or is it happening upon receipt? Can you test `str` before calling `atof`?

Comment: `%lf` caused undefined behaviour in C89; perhaps you're on an old compiler? Try with `%f`.

Comment: This sounds a lot like %lf isn't defined, and the parsing of it is breaking at %l, failing to print anything useful, and then printing "f" as just normal text. Note that old versions of printf (like the one in SunOS 4.1.3 in the 1980s) didn't support %lf, instead "l" was reserved for "d, i, o, u, x, or X conversions".  %lf is appropriate for a "long float" - usually 16 bytes, not just 8.

Comment: All right, I found that the printf doesn't support float printing (both %f and %lf,and also %a). I'm now trying to reconvert the float in a string of characters to see if the conversion or the calculus are done correctly, but how can I do since sprintf won't work? Thank you all!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302969/how-to-implement-char-ftoafloat-num-without-sprintf-library-function-i , ftp://ftp-archive.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD-Archive/old-releases/i386/1.0-RELEASE/ports/ingres/source/gutil/ftoa.c