# Convert double to string in scientific notation faster than sprintf in c++

Tags: c++, string, double, number-formatting, scientific-notation

Just as the title, how do I convert double to string in scientific notation faster than `sprintf` in c++?

I have lots of (about 1e10) double numbers, and have to convert all to string in this format: ±*.*********E±***, which has 10 significance digits.

But `sprintf` and `stringstream` are too slow, Is there any faster way?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to compare speed if strintf with speed of sstream with output manipulators? I suppose sprintf is faster :-)

Comment: of course `sprintf` is faster than `stringstream`, but i want faster than `sprintf`.

Comment: Are you sure that sprintf is too slow? If you have doubles, what do you need strings for? Are you sure that it's not the operation you need the string for that is so slow?

Comment: Yes i am sure after profiling in VS2013.

Comment: Does order matter?  What are you outputting these 10 billion strings to, a file on a spinning disk?  Have you determined that formatting is your bottleneck, and if so how did you do this, and what are the profiling resuts?

Comment: Sprintf is very, very fast. It is tuned for speed by generations of programmers. The only way you can get it any faster is to get yourself the source code of sprintf and throw away everything that you don't need. Instead of parsing the format it should use your hardcoded values for precision and width.

Comment: Though I too wonder why you would need 10 billion strings for. Are you going to import them in a spreadsheet or what?

Comment: Well, it's a external sorting task, sort 10 billion doubles and store them in this format, after frofiling, `sprintf` took 20% time, so i want to improve it.

Comment: @n.m. well, that's what i want, but i don't know how to implement my own `sprintf`, could you help me?

Comment: As I said, you need to read source code for an existing implementation of `sprintf`, understand it, and modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: @n.m. But i couldn't find any existing implementation of `sprintf`. After stepping into the code, i got `_cfltcvt_l` function, but there is not `_cfltcvt_l` source code in Windows; in Linux, i got `__mingw_vsprintf`, the same, no source code.

Comment: "couldn't find any existing implementation of sprintf" glibc is open source. http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/download.html

Answer (score 1):

Using boost is a way out

```
std::string str = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(dbl);
```

The normal approach:

```
std::ostringstream strs;
strs << dbl;
std::string str = strs.str();
```

***You should use*** `sprintf()` ***as it is the fastest.***

*Run Time of different functions @ http://zverovich.net/2013/09/07/integer-to-string-conversion-in-cplusplus.html*

References: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/166322/converting-number-from-long-double-to-string

*Need more help? Let me know*

Comment: Is `boost` faster than `sprintf`? And I want my string in this format: ±*.*********E±***, which has 10 significance digits, how can i do?

Comment: there is a nice article on performance here http://zverovich.net/2013/09/07/integer-to-string-conversion-in-cplusplus.html , sprintf is faster

Comment: So,  Is there any way faster than `sprintf`?

Comment: Your link said `fmt::Writer` is fastest when converting int to string, but i want to convert double to string in scientific notation, is that the same?

Answer (score 0):

The conversion you ask for is not a simple operation. You can have a look at [How to implement " char * ftoa(float num) " without sprintf() library function in C, C++ and JAVA?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2302969/3545273) to be sure.

I'm not sure that you will find an implementation that will be quicker that sprintf, because it is in standard C library for a time and can already have been optimised.

The best you can do is :

- get the source from a standard C library
- analyse how the conversion is done
- compare with the links found in the question cited above
- benchmark different implementations

I understand it is more a hint than a full annswer, but it is both too long for a comment and the best I can do

Comment: But i couldn't find any existing implementation of sprintf. After stepping into the code, i got `_cfltcvt_l` function, but there is not `_cfltcvt_l` source code in Windows; in Linux, i got `__mingw_vsprintf`, the same, no source code.